# dependencies error while installing teamviewer in centOS 6.4 64bit?

Tags: linux, centos6, yum

Hello I am using centos 6.4 64bit. i am trying to install teamviewer. i've downloaded teamviewer rpm from teamviewer site. when i run

```
rpm -ivh teamviewer_10.0.37742.i686.rpm
```

it shows me `failed dependencies` error so i start to install dependencies by using **yum** but some dependencies unable to install which are

```
warning: teamviewer_10.0.37742.i686.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 72db573c: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        libfontconfig.so.1 is needed by teamviewer-10.0.37742-0.i686
        libjpeg.so.62 is needed by teamviewer-10.0.37742-0.i686
        libXinerama.so.1 is needed by teamviewer-10.0.37742-0.i686
        libXrandr.so.2 is needed by teamviewer-10.0.37742-0.i686
        libXrender.so.1 is needed by teamviewer-10.0.37742-0.i686
```

when i run `yum install libfontconfig.so.1`

i got this error

```
    warning: teamviewer_10.0.37742.i686.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 72db573c: NOKEY
    error: Failed dependencies:
            libfontconfig.so.1 is needed by teamviewer-10.0.37742-0.i686
            libjpeg.so.62 is needed by teamviewer-10.0.37742-0.i686
            libXinerama.so.1 is needed by teamviewer-10.0.37742-0.i686
            libXrandr.so.2 is needed by teamviewer-10.0.37742-0.i686
            libXrender.so.1 is needed by teamviewer-10.0.37742-0.i686

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, protectbase, refresh-packagekit, security
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
     * base: centos.excellmedia.net
     * epel: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
     * extras: centos.excellmedia.net
     * linuxtech-release: pkgrepo.linuxtech.net
     * updates: centos.excellmedia.net
     * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
    0 packages excluded due to repository protections
    Setting up Install Process
    Resolving Dependencies
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package fontconfig.i686 0:2.8.0-5.el6 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: libexpat.so.1 for package: fontconfig-2.8.0-5.el6.i686
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package expat.i686 0:2.0.1-11.el6_2 will be installed
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution
    Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
           cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
           pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

             1. You have an upgrade for fontconfig which is missing some
                dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
                solve this by installing an older version of fontconfig of the
                different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
                yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
                requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
                --exclude fontconfig.otherarch ... this should give you an error
                message showing the root cause of the problem.

             2. You have multiple architectures of fontconfig installed, but
                yum can only see an upgrade for one of those arcitectures.
                If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
                can remove the one with the missing update and everything
                will work.

             3. You have duplicate versions of fontconfig installed already.
                You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

           ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
           this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
           do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
           much more problems).

           Protected multilib versions: fontconfig-2.8.0-5.el6.i686 != fontconfig-2.8.0-3.el6.x86_64
     You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
     You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

so what should i do i've tried many things but didn't success?

Comment: That is more suited on http://superuser.com, however, have you checked their [FAQ entry](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/363-How-do-I-install-TeamViewer-on-my-Linux-distribution.aspx#other) and installed it like they say?

Comment: Have you run that `rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest` command? What does it say? What about `yum check`? That error indicates that you are trying to install a mismatched multilib version of fontconfig. Make sure your repositories are up-to-date and try `yum update fontconfig` to see if it can manage to update both versions (if you don't have the `i686` version installed currently try `yum install fontconfig.i386 fontconfig.x86_64` maybe?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TeamViewer for Linux is compiled on x86 (i686) platform, so you must install x86-based dependency packages, which you can find at [rpmfind.net](http://rpmfind.net).

Answer (score 1):

On

```
# uname -a
Linux centos6.6.6.71092 2.6.32-042stab108.1 #1 SMP Thu Apr 23 19:17:11 MSK 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This works for me without errors:

```
# wget http://www.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_linux.rpm
# yum install teamviewer_linux.rpm
```

> [If you get missing public key error, you can download public key and
>   import it using the following command continue](http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-install-teamviewer-on-linux-distributions/)

Answer (score 0):

TeamViewer for Linux (OpenSuse, CentOS etc..) is compiled on x86 platform, so you have to install x86-based dependency packages